# return type of a variadic template member function

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I have been trying to keep track of all the requests I made through a thread pool system. So I can check if they are completed or not in every system tick which happens 60 (fps) times in a second.

```
class data : public data_base {
public:
    data (std::string, bool);
};
class thread_pool {
public:
    template<class F, class... Args>
    auto enqueue(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> decltype(auto)
    {
        //a task to run in a seperate thread;
        auto task = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<typename std::invoke_result<F, Args...>
            ::type()>>(std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...));

        std::future<typename std::invoke_result<F, Args...>::type> result = task->get_future();

        return result;
    }
};

class loader {
    thread_pool pool_;
public:
    template<typename T, typename ...Ts>
    auto load_async(std::string& key, Ts... args) -> decltype(auto) {
        //return = pool_.enqueue([this, key, args...]() {
        return pool_.enqueue([this, key, args...]() {
            ///work work work
            });
    }
};

class user{
public:
    void use() {
        loader loader_;
        auto return_type = 1;//get return type of loader::load_async
        std::map<std::string, return_type> requests;

        //someone may decide to roll his own data class with different params.
        requests["key"] = loader_.load_async<data>("key", true);

    }
};

int main()
{
    user u;
    u.use();
}
```

Now I need to get return type of `loader::load_async` in `user::use`.

1. Is this a good idea ?
2. If yes then how can I get the return type of `loader::load_async` ?
3. Is there any much more suitable solution that you can think of ?

Comment: `using return_type = decltype(std::declval<loader>().load_async<data>(std::string(""), true));` helps but do i have to state exact parameters every time?

Comment: `return = pool_.enqueue`... is this valid C++.  I think not. What's with the `=` ?

Comment: I also don't see the point of adding a key to a local variable map `requests` and then abandoning it immediately.  Is that list of requests supposed to be able to handle a request of any type?  Do you need a base type for a request?  It looks like you want to manage a collection of requests _independently_ of their return type.  Worst case: `std::any` can hold it.

Comment: @Wyck Yes, the code as posted needs a rethink, I reckon.